# Converting Visual Basic Code to .NET Framework

Tags: .net, vba

Can someone recommend a service that facilitates conversion of visual basic code to .NET framework (preferably C#)?

I have 2 desktop applications, each with over 100,000 lines of code. Would like to see if it’s possible to convert it effectively. Would also appreciate it if pricing is transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at **https://phoenix.selise.ch/** for conversion to C#. They offer free consultation, so that may be a good way to estimate costs or understand exactly how their process works.

Comment: is ths a piece of software or a service?

Comment: It's a service with support of tool that analyze the scope of migration. @DeveloperACE
Try downloading the tool from here 

https://phoenix.selise.ch/phoenix-assessment-tool?index=headerMenu4

Analyze your code yourself with the tool and email phoenix the report from the assessment tool. Their engineers will get back to you for an hour of free consultation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Exploring the options.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider the services of https://www.vbmigration.com/
VbMigration is headed by Francesco Balena, a great VB developer.